# Magento - Rename Tax to GST

Tags: magento, web

Throughout my Magento website, where there are products, I made it so that a customer can see the price of the products, with and without Tax.

However, how can I rename the word 'Tax' to 'GST' whenever a product is viewed within the website. I believe I have to go to the back-end and change some script around, I just don't know where?

Comment: This is something you can alternate your GST set up. https://magecomp.com/blog/create-gst-tax-rule-magento/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to translate inline.See [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/) to enable the inline translation from admin panel. Now hover over the "Tax" you can see the book icon click on that and type whatever text you want to replace with, in your case its "GST".

Another way is to directly changing in the csv files in app/locale folder.According to the locale you have choosen, for example if you have choosen "United States" than check for the file Mage_Tax.csv file inside "app/locale/en_US/Mage_Tax.csv". After opening this file search for term "Tax","Tax".Change it to "Tax","GST". and save it.

Hope this will help.

Comment: See, I have already tried both of those things. When I enable the inline translation and click on the red dotted area I want to change, it doesn't do anything. And I have already exported the Mage_Tax.csv file from en_US file and changed 'Tax' to 'GST' on the right column only and still nothing has changed. I appreciate your answer however and trying to help me.

Comment: In which browser have you tried inline translation? For me it didn't work in chrome but it works in firefox and IE. Try that.

Comment: I am using chrome. I'll try Firefox and see how I go.

Comment: Okay, so with Firefox, I am able to get the Inline translation box up, though when I tick the checkbox and replace 'Tax' with 'GST' as well as refresh, nothing changed.

Comment: If that doesnot work have you tried the second method that worked for me .To make second method work you should edit in your correct locale For example if you have set your locale for Australia you should change the file within the foleder en_AU like wise.

Comment: The files I have is en_US (and en_ES if relevant) but I don't have en_AU? And my locale options are set as English (Australia) or AUS. Does this mean I should change the en_US folder to en_AU?

Comment: you can create a folder en_AU and copy that file inside that folder and make amendments there.

Comment: So simply, create a new folder called en_AU and copy that file only into that folder? Okay I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. It only shows 'Incl. Tax' rather than 'Incl. GST'. I feel like this is just unsolvable.

Comment: Which text you replaced in the file?If you want to change 'Incl. Tax' than replace that line not the line with only "Tax". Have you done that?

Comment: Yes I have, even Excl. Tax. Basically everything that has the word Tax I changed to GST (only on the right column, not the left one).